# Facebook: Share story without adding link to resource

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to make users to be able to post stories to their timeline but with no links to any resources. Using Facebook example:

[image: facebook sample post]

I would like this post not to have any links. If someone using facebook on a browser clicks the image or the Cookie! title, they will be redirected somewhere. In my case, they are directed to an URL on my api which stores object data as meta tags from where FB scrappes the information (in this case, a blank page where the headers describe the Cookie! object). Is this even possible? I am developing an app for ios with no website, this is why I need to do this.

Comment: You can use the Object API that is described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects

Comment: @WizKid, I am using the graph-api already. Everything is working, the thing is I don't want the post image nor title to be a link. It is pointing to the url FB used to scrappe information on that object.

Comment: If you are posting a url there will be a link. Nothing you can do to change that

Comment: I am posting an action over an Object whose data is represented at an url through meta tags. When the link is clicked, user is redirected to this url which holds only metadata. I don't have a web interface which displays information on these objects. Anyone? ={

Comment: If you don't have a web interface I would suggest that you use the Object API. That will do what you want.

Comment: @WizKid, at first I didn't understand what you were saying but after taking a better look into the Object Api I understood. It seems this is the best solution in this case, but when I create a new object it won't be self hosted. I am doing this for now.